# How to get IP address from Google web history

Tags: google-account, ip-address

Robbers have stolen my laptop and it seems they are using my Google Account on Chrome. Gmail shows me only the last ten login's but I need more.

Can I find their IP addresses from Google web history? Is it possible?

Comment: Doubt it will work, maybe look through the web history for geo-tagged pages

Answer (score 1):

To track the IP who used your Google Account:

1. Go to the Account after clicking on the icon at the top right
   corner of Google account and then move to the Devices option 
   under the Recent activity.
2. Now you can click on the Manage  all devices connected to your Google account which would show the devices using the Google Account.

Answer (score -1):

do you have your mac address?  it may be in your emails; it may be in the network logs of routers to which you were attached.  from the mac address you MAY be able to get, if not the IP, the location, with tools such as [samy.pl/mapxss/](http://samy.pl/mapxss/) or [samy.pl/androidmap/](http://samy.pl/androidmap/) -- also check out various perl scripts exploiting skyhook and the locate-me feature of the iphone.

Comment: I really don't see why having the laptop's MAC address would help.